# how to add rows to table view dynamically while scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

table view should a rows to table view when i am scrollig..

how to do that..

Comment: Oh my goodness. Not only is your question completely incomprehensible, it appears to have absolutely nothing to with Xcode (I'll retag that for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataSource does not have to rely on static data.

Make up new rows on the fly when DataSource is queried for new rows through

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```